# How to use checkbox inside notifyNotification?

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, kotlin

The functions I want to implement are:
If the checkbox is on when the alarm goes off, hand over the value to the firebase.

notifyNotification confirmed that there is no problem.

I can't use findViewById inside notifyNotification so I leave a question.
How can I use findViewById?

[This is the result I tried to solve without using findViewBy.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5CMj.jpg)

I couldn't find the name of the checkbox here. Below is the notifyNotification code. How can I implement the function?

```
class AlarmReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {


    companion object {
        const val NOTIFICATION_ID = 100
        const val NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "1000"

    }

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        createNotificationChannel(context)
        notifyNotification(context)

    }

    private fun createNotificationChannel(context: Context) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(
                NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID,
                "기상 알람",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            )

            NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)


        }
    }

    private fun notifyNotification(context: Context) {

        with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)) {

            val build = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("알람")
                .setContentText("일어날 시간입니다.")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)


            notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, build.build())

            val firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            val databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.reference

            if (checkBox.isChecked == true) {
                databaseReference.child("c").setValue("C")

            }
        }
    }

}
```

ACTIVITY_MAIN

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_white_ring"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/onOffButton"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.496"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.12" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/timeTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="09:30"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/ampmTextView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.20999998"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ampmTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="AM"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/timeTextView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/onOffButton" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/onOffButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/on_alarm"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/changeAlarmTimeButton"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/changeAlarmTimeButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
    android:text="@string/change_time"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="88dp"
    android:text="SCAN"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/onOffButton"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button3"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="88dp"
    android:text="SCAN"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/onOffButton"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button2" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:buttonTint="#FFFFFF"
    android:text="A :"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/onOffButton"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:buttonTint="#FFFFFF"
    android:text="B :"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/onOffButton"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/checkbox2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/checkbox" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="92dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:buttonTint="#FFFFFF"
    android:checked="false"
    android:focusable="auto"
    android:text="C :"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/onOffButton"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="117dp"
    android:layout_height="29dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:text="오늘의 날씨"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.486"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="193dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="192dp"
    android:text="맑음"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.454"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="421dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:text="소독하기"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/changeAlarmTimeButton"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
```

MAIN ACTIVITY

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        initOnOffButton()
        initChangeAlarmTimeButton()

        val model = fetchDataFromSharedPreferences()
        renderView(model)

        val firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        val databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.reference

        val sendbt = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button2)
        sendbt.setOnClickListener{
            databaseReference.child("scan").setValue("a")
        }

        val sendbt2 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button3)
        sendbt2.setOnClickListener{
            databaseReference.child("scan").setValue("b")
        }

        val sendbt3 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button4)
        sendbt3.setOnClickListener{
            databaseReference.child("sodok").setValue("s")

            Handler().postDelayed({
                databaseReference.child("sodok").setValue("S")
            }, 5000)

        }

    }


    private fun initOnOffButton() {
        val onOffButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.onOffButton)
        onOffButton.setOnClickListener {

            val model = it.tag as? AlarmDisplayModel ?: return@setOnClickListener
            val newModel = saveAlarmModel(model.hour, model.minute, model.onOff.not())
            renderView(newModel)

            if (newModel.onOff) {
                // 켜진 경우 -> 알람을 등록
                val calendar = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
                    set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, newModel.hour)
                    set(Calendar.MINUTE, newModel.minute)

                    if (before(Calendar.getInstance())) {
                        add(Calendar.DATE, 1)
                    }
                }

                val alarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
                val intent = Intent(this, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
                val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, ALARM_REQUEST_CODE,
                        intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
                
                alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(
                    AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    calendar.timeInMillis,
                    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                    pendingIntent
                )

            }

            else {
                cancelAlarm()
            }

        }
    }

    private fun initChangeAlarmTimeButton() {
        val changeAlarmButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.changeAlarmTimeButton)
        changeAlarmButton.setOnClickListener {

            //현재 시간을 가져오기 위해 캘린터 인스턴스 사용
            val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
            //타임다이얼로그 띄워줘서 시간을 설정, 그 시간을 가져옴
            TimePickerDialog(this, { picker, hour, minute ->

                // 데이터 저장
                val model = saveAlarmModel(hour, minute, false)
                //뷰 업데이트
                renderView(model)

                //기존 알람 삭제
                cancelAlarm()

            }, calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), false).show()

        }

    }

    private fun saveAlarmModel(
        hour: Int,
        minute: Int,
        onOff: Boolean
    ): AlarmDisplayModel {
        val model = AlarmDisplayModel(
            hour = hour,
            minute = minute,
            onOff = onOff
        )

        //시간에 대한 db파일 생성
        val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

        //edit 모드로 열어서 작업 (값 저장)
        with(sharedPreferences.edit()) {
            putString(ALARM_KEY, model.makeDataForDB())
            putBoolean(ONOFF_KEY, model.onOff)
            commit()
        }

        return model
    }

    private fun fetchDataFromSharedPreferences():AlarmDisplayModel {
        val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

        //DB에서 데이터 가져오기
        val timeDBValue = sharedPreferences.getString(ALARM_KEY, "9:30") ?: "9:30"
        val onOffDBValue = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(ONOFF_KEY, false)

        //시 : 분 형식으로 가져온 데이터 스플릿
        val alarmData = timeDBValue.split(":")

        val alarmModel = AlarmDisplayModel(
            hour = alarmData[0].toInt(),
            minute = alarmData[1].toInt(),
            onOff = onOffDBValue
        )

        // 보정 보정 예외처리

        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, ALARM_REQUEST_CODE, Intent(this, AlarmReceiver::class.java), PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE)

        if ((pendingIntent == null) and alarmModel.onOff) {
            // 알람은 꺼져있는데, 데이터는 켜저있는 경우
            alarmModel.onOff = false


        } else if ((pendingIntent != null) and alarmModel.onOff.not()){
            // 알람은 켜져있는데, 데이터는 꺼져있는 경우
            // 알람을 취소함
            pendingIntent.cancel()
        }

        return alarmModel

    }

    private fun renderView(model: AlarmDisplayModel) {
        //최초 실행 또는 시간 재설정 시 들어오게 되는 부분

        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.ampmTextView).apply {
            text = model.ampmText
        }

        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.timeTextView).apply {
            text = model.timeText
        }

        findViewById<Button>(R.id.onOffButton).apply {
            text = model.onOffText
            tag = model
        }

    }

    private fun cancelAlarm() {
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, ALARM_REQUEST_CODE, Intent(this, AlarmReceiver::class.java), PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE)
        pendingIntent?.cancel()
    }

    companion object {
        private const val SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME = "time"
        private const val ALARM_KEY = "alarm"
        private const val ONOFF_KEY = "onOff"
        private const val ALARM_REQUEST_CODE = 1000

    }
```

Comment: How are `checkbox` and `checkbox1` defined?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply because I was sick. 
Edited the text. I just need to be able to use findViewByID(int). I've seen several examples. But I couldn't understand it because it was a little different from me.

Comment: The question remains, how are checkbox and checkbox1 defined?

Comment: They are defined as checkBox and checkBox1 respectively... 
I did not change the id separately.

Comment: Add those declarations to your question.

Comment: i added my code

Comment: Not in the layout file, but in your activity code.

Comment: Did I make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Show us how you have defined those views in your activity code.